# How to stop paramiko from using ~/.ssh/id_rsa encrypted key?

Tags: paramiko

I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/d/workspace/paramiko/connect_test/main.py", line 127, in connect
    cStringIO.StringIO(local_settings.RSA_KEY)
  File "/home/d/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 380, in connect
    look_for_keys, gss_auth, gss_kex, gss_deleg_creds, gss_host)
  File "/home/d/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 603, in _auth
    raise saved_exception
paramiko.ssh_exception.PasswordRequiredException: Private key file is encrypted
```

The thing is that I added the key I'd like to use this way and it's not encrypted:

```
                ssh_client.connect(
                    node_ip, username=local_settings.USERNAME,
                    pkey=paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key(
                        cStringIO.StringIO(local_settings.RSA_KEY)
                    )
                )
```

I think it's looking at my encrypted private key ~/.ssh/id_rsa. Is there a way I could stop it from doing it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Paramiko tries to fallback to your `~/.ssh/` keys and only reports the last error. You can disable the fallback behavior by passing `look_for_keys=False` to `connect()`, which then should raise a more helpful exception.